# Dynamo db query using contains operator

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My table items are of the form of

```
function addDoc(movie,cb){
    var params = {
        TableName: "Movies",
        Item: {
            "year":  movie.year,
            "title": movie.title,
            "info":  movie.info,
            "genres" : movie.info.genres || []
        }
    };
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        bar.tick(1)
        i++;
        cb(err);
    });
}

async.eachLimit(allMovies,50,addDoc,function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log("done inserting " + i + " movies");
});
```

I'm running this code :

```
var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    //ProjectionExpression:"#yr, title, genres, info.actors[0]",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#yr = :yyyy and contains(genres, :g1)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#yr": "year"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":yyyy":1992,
        ":g1" : "Drama"
    },
    //Select : "COUNT"
};
var start = Date.now()
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("time elapsed :",Date.now()-start);
        console.log("Query succeeded.");

        console.log(data)

    }
});
```

and I'm getting this error

> "Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: contains"

any idea?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are few things that need to be clarified here.

1) The Key attributes of DynamoDB has to be scalar data type. So, I believe the attribute `genres` can't be defined as SET or LIST data type

2) `KeyConditionExpression` - can refer to Hash and Sort key only. So, I presume the attribute `genres` is defined as SORT key of the table

3) `contains` can be used on `FilterExpression` on data types STRING, SET or LIST. It can't be used on `KeyConditionExpression`

**Conclusion** - Refer **point 3** for straight forward answer

Comment: any idea how to perform seaching in text? as in substring searching? ex: search for **blue** in **blue screen error**

Comment: @sid8491 You can use CONTAINS. Please note that it is a case sensitive match.      FilterExpression: "contains (title, :titleVal)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":titleVal": "somevalue"
    }

Comment: but the field with which i want to match it is `string` field, and you mentioned it can be used on SET or LIST type only

Comment: @sid8491 it can be used for string as well.

Comment: but the example here showed that `contains` can be used on `KeyConditionExpression` ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html

Comment: @MKYung I'm also totally confused by now. Official docs clearly shows that 'contains' can me used in KeyConditionExpression

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SDK documentation, KeyConditionExpression supports the following expressions:

a = b — true if the attribute a is equal to the value b

a < b — true if a is less than b

a <= b — true if a is less than or equal to b

a > b — true if a is greater than b

a >= b — true if a is greater than or equal to b

a BETWEEN b AND c — true if a is greater than or equal to b, and less than or equal to c.

The following function is also supported:

begins_with (a, substr)— true if the value of attribute a begins with a particular substring.

see documentation page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html